# Unable to get expected result with Date() method in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I am working on a music application. If a music file has been added then I should get the duration (which is in milliseconds) and convert the duration into minutes.

```
var d = new Date(ms);
var hms = d.getMinutes().toString() +':'+ d.getSeconds().toString();
```

If I am providing `ms = 331807;`

`expected answer is = 11:42` but the `result is = 41:02`
I am unable to figure out the problem. Can anyone please help me find the solution?

Comment: How exactly `331807 ms` should NOT convert into `331.807 sec` (which is actually 5 minutes 31 sec) is a mystery to me, I'm afraid.

Comment: As a sidenote, how exactly is this question related to PHP, mootools and zend framework? `datetime` tag looks to be far more relevant.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Fhyc7/ getting 5:31, like @raina77ow said..

Comment: And as another sidenote, I'd rather use more primitive logic here: `var s = ms/1000; var dur = [s/60, s%60].join(':');` or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Date` object expects milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 UTC.  However, the `getMinutes` and `getSeconds` functions will be output relative to the time zone that the code is running in.

If you want to use the `Date` object for this, you should use the `getUTCMinutes` and `getUTCSeconds` instead.

However, as others pointed out, this isn't the best use case for the `Date` object.  You can do simple math to convert milliseconds to minutes and seconds.

Comment: If im using getUTCMinutes and getUTCSeconds.The result is Expected to have:0:29 but the result is:0:58........(Sorry I got the answer corrctly but unable to remove the comment)...Thankyou for this clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The `Date` constructor instantiates a new object with an optional argument passed to it. Passing an amount of milliseconds to it gives you a new `Date` object, which is a date and time since the epoch, relative to the number of milliseconds you passed to it. `getMinutes` probably gave you 42, because the time you passed to the `Date` constructor was at the 42nd minute of whatever date was constructed.

You can convert milliseconds to minutes with simple multiplication.

```
numberOfMilliseconds / (1000*60)
```